# Scraping contents of title from an 'a' tag

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using nokogiri to scrape contents from https://www.nba.com/teams/warriors but I am unable to scrape the contents from the a tag.

I played around with adding and removing the classes but I receive an empty array.

`base_url.css(".nba-player-index__trending-item a ['title']").map(&:text)`

I would like to see: Jordan Bell.[Image of the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR43n.png)

Comment: Remove the space after the a.

Comment: ```base_url.css(".nba-player-index__trending-item a['title']").map(&:text)```  didn't work

Comment: sorry, just `a[title]` - You can do ctrl+f in the browser elements panel to search with css

Comment: Well there's always the possibility that it's not there.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages at the bottom of the page, along with "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need you to provide the minimum snippet of the HTML that helps to demonstrate the problem rather than ask us to load the page and search it. Also, please don't use links to images that demonstrate essential parts of the question. Links can break and images can't be reused to enter data as we're working on solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the title values with:

```
base_url.css(".nba-player-index__trending-item a:first").map{|item| item[:title] }
```